# rpc.idmapd not starting on boot

Tags: kubuntu, nfs

I'm having an issue with name mappings when accessing an NFSv4 (w/ Kerberos) server I've set up from by Kubuntu 14.10 box.

Earlier documentation mentions setting NEED_IDMAPD in /etc/defaults/nfs-common. However, this appears to have disappeared from the current version of the config file. Adding it manually has had no effect.

Checking or the process with ps -ef | grep idmapd does not show the process as present. However, running service idmapd restart apparently brings it up (service idmap start claims that the process is already running, even though this does not appear to be the case). Console output:

```
root@kerensky:/home/notavi# service idmapd status
idmapd start/running
root@kerensky:/home/notavi# ps -ef | grep idmap
root      4761  4363  0 21:08 pts/5    00:00:00 grep --color=auto idmap
root@kerensky:/home/notavi# service idmapd restart
idmapd stop/waiting
idmapd start/running, process 4780
root@kerensky:/home/notavi# ps -ef | grep idmap
root      4780     1  0 21:08 ?        00:00:00 rpc.idmapd
root      4783  4363  0 21:08 pts/5    00:00:00 grep --color=auto idmap
root@kerensky:/home/notavi#
```

Once brought up, everything else is working. I just need to figure out what's wrong with the startup process. Checking the logs turns up very little information:

```
Feb  9 20:55:07 kerensky kernel: init: idmapd main process (673) terminated with status 1
Feb  9 20:55:07 kerensky kernel: init: idmapd main process ended, respawning
```

There doesn't appear to be any other information in the log, despite Verbosity being set to 5 in /etc/idmapd.conf Once restarted manually I can see the full debugging log output present.